# Questions on passing variables to other classes after reading a file

Tags: java

Currently my readfile class reads a txt file, and the txt file has full of lines like this: a, b, c. I use the split() to separate the line to three parts. After that I want to pass those three parts for the other class that will use them, in the other class, it has the getmethod for both a and b,c (b and c can be retrieved as a List).

I already split them but don't know how to pass the value to the class to use them, should I call the class in my readfile method? Thanks!

```
public static Final read(String fileName) throws IOException, FormatException {
    FileReader filereader = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(filereader);
    String line = bufferreader.readLine();
    while (line != null){
        for (String separatedLine: line.split("/n")){

        }
        line = bufferreader.readLine();
    }
    bufferreader.close();
}
```

For example, the txt will look like "1 a1 Apple a2 Banana", (a1 Apple a2 Banana are saved as a list in the other class)

Comment: @FastSnail just put on it

Comment: You can't pass a variable to a class, you can only call a method of the class or an instance using parameters. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @YogeshPatil `Final` is the other class too, and this class is called `FinalReader`, so it uses to read the data and give the data to the `Final` class and other class.

Comment: @DisplayName This class is calles `FinalReader`, it read the txt and pass the data to `Final` (the other class) after spliting the data. So I should create some variable to store a and b,c separately?

Comment: Rather than return `Final' object from method, you should pass the `Final` class object as argument to the read method, and call setter method, which is used in `Final` class to set the split line.

Comment: @Sandeep.K Actually is a long java package so I can only tell some about it. So, it has 3 classes `Final`, `FinalReader` and `Process`. `FinalReader` read the input file, `Process` and `Final` will do sth on the data from the file. First of all, I have to put the line (separated already) into an object `Process`. After finish all the thing, the object `Process` will pass to object `Final`.

Comment: @HuiTingKo You are saying that you have to put the lines into an object `Process`. So is process have some method for you to set that lines??

Comment: @Sandeep.K For example, the "1" is called figure, and it has a getFigure() in the Process and in that method, it returns figure, can u get it? I am so weak at java so i may not explain well enough and I cant upload the whole file here, so...can u get it?